# Wordpress: Display only 2nd level taxonomy terms

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, categories, taxonomy

I have a custom post type of 'stories'. I have a taxonomy of 'story_categories'. I need to display the top level categories, and below these the child categories. It works fine with the following code...

```
<?php
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    $term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
    $list_child_terms_args = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'story_categories',
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of' => $term_id
    );
?>
<ul class="list list-links list-links-small">
    <?php wp_list_categories( $list_child_terms_args ); ?>
</ul>
```

...up until I click one of the subcategories. Then I get 'No categories' (I assume this is because it's always looking for the subcategories of the *current* page, and the subcategory has none of these).

Is there a way to use the above code in a way where it always displays the subcategories of a certain level, even if I'm in a subcategory? eg:

```
Stories (top level)
--News (2nd level) < Always display subcats of this at all times
--Events (2nd level) < Always display subcats of this at all times
---Stuff (3rd level)
---Stuff (3rd level)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you're passing `child_of` the current term. To fix it, simply retrieve the root parent of your current term.

### Option 1

```
// Loop until you reach the top parent term
$root = $queried_object;
while($root->parent != '0')
    $root = get_term_by('id', $root->parent, $root->taxonomy);
```

Then once you've retrieve the root, update your args like this:

```
'child_of' => $root->term_id
```

### Option 2

If you don't want to loop, you can use [get_ancestors](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_ancestors):

```
$parents = get_ancestors($term_id, $queried_object->taxonomy, 'taxonomy');
```

Then pass the last element:

```
'child_of' => $parents ? end($parents) : $term_id
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'd preferably not loop, but the 2nd suggestion simply displays everything at all times. eg: https://i.imgur.com/HtNUxM9.jpg

Comment: @Phill What do you mean?

Comment: Sorry, I attached an image. Here's the code as well: https://i.imgur.com/rHnwo70.jpg

Comment: @Phill Can you do a `var_dump($parents);` to see the returned value?

Comment: Sure, it comes back as: array(0) { }

Here's where the CPT is created: https://i.imgur.com/qJlio6b.png

Comment: @Phill Ah, are you at the root category already? Take a look at my update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165016/discussion-between-phill-and-chin-leung).